# Transposicion de Columnas en una Matriz en c++

Tags: c++, array, ordenamiento

Hola tengo una matriz char inicializada de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

main(){

char matriz[6][5]={
{'F','H','V','D','U'},
{'E','L','Q','U','E'},
{'P','E','R','S','E'},
{'V','E','R','A','A'},
{'L','C','A','N','Z'},
{'A','Z','Z','Z','Z'}};

}
```

Y necesito transponer las columnas, ordenando alfabéticamente la primera fila, es decir, la fila que contiene {'F','H','V','D','U'}.

La matriz que necesito obtener es la siguiente:

```
char matriz[6][5]={
{'D','F','H','U','V'},
{'U','E','L','E','Q'},
{'S','P','E','E','R'},
{'A','V','E','A','R'},
{'N','L','C','Z','A'},
{'Z','A','Z','Z','Z'}};
```

He logrado ordenar alfabéticamente la primera fila únicamente, pero no logro como poder mover el resto de la columna para efectuar el ordenamiento como un solo bloque.

**Actualizacion:**

Ok finalmente logre poder trasponerla pero ahora por lo menos si la primera fila de la matriz tiene letras iguales, se ordenan alfabeticamente pero se transponen los valores de solamente una de las dos columnas. He aqui el codigo que tengo para trasponerlas.

```
    for(int j=0;j<largo;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<largo;i++){
            if(textoB[0][j]==texto[0][i]&&textoB[0][j+1]==texto[0][i]){
                texto[0][i]='*';
                for(int k=1;k<fila;k++){
                    textoB[k][j]=texto[k][i];
                }
            }


            else if(textoB[0][j]==texto[0][i])
                for(int k=1;k<fila;k++){
                    textoB[k][j]=texto[k][i];
                }
        }
    }
```

Siendo texto la matriz original desordenada y textoB la matriz original con primera fila ordenada alfabéticamente (desordenada en las demás espacios).

Comment: Que haz intentado hacer ?

Comment: He logrado transponerlas como me lo piden, ahora lo que mi codigo no hace es diferenciar las letras que son iguales al momento de hacer la transposicion.

Answer (score 1):

No has publicado tu código de manera que no podemos saber en qué te has equivocado, podría ser incluso un caso de [¿Qué has intentado?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

> no logro como poder mover el resto de la columna para efectuar el ordenamiento como un solo bloque

El *problema* es que estás trabajando con una matriz de dos dimensiones, que hace un poco más incómodo el intercambiar la información de las columnas, no puedes tratarlas como "un solo bloque" pues pertenecen a bloques diferentes. En memoria debe tener un aspecto parecido a...

```
fila       |    0    |    1    |    2    |    3    |    4    |    5    |
columna    |0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|
memoria    |F|H|V|D|U|E|L|Q|U|E|P|E|R|S|E|V|E|R|A|A|L|C|A|N|Z|A|Z|Z|Z|Z|
```

Así que debes recorrer las filas una por una e intercambiar los valores de las columas que te interese. La aproximación que te aconsejo es la siguiente:

```
for (std::size_t fila = 0u; fila != FILAS; ++fila)
{
    // 'izquierda' y 'derecha' son las columnas que se quieren intercambiar
    std::swap(matriz[fila][izquierda], matriz[fila][derecha]);
}
```

Yo he usado una solución basada en plantillas que permite matrices de dos dimensiones de tipos y tamaños arbitrarios (siempre y cuando el tipo facilitado disponga de operador `<`):

```
template <typename TIPO, std::size_t FILAS, std::size_t COLUMNAS>
void intercambia_columnas(TIPO (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS], std::size_t izquierda, std::size_t derecha)
{
    for (std::size_t fila = 0u; fila != FILAS; ++fila)
    {
        std::swap(matriz[fila][izquierda], matriz[fila][derecha]);
    }
}
template <typename TIPO, std::size_t FILAS, std::size_t COLUMNAS>
int compara_columnas(const TIPO (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS], std::size_t izquierda, std::size_t derecha)
{
    for (std::size_t fila = 0u; fila != FILAS; ++fila)
    {
        const auto i = matriz[fila][izquierda], d = matriz[fila][derecha];

        if (i != d)
        {
            return i < d ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

template <typename TIPO, std::size_t FILAS, std::size_t COLUMNAS>
void ordena_matriz(TIPO (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS])
{
    for (std::size_t a = 0u; a != COLUMNAS - 1u; ++a)
    {
        for (std::size_t b = a + 1u; b != COLUMNAS; ++b)
        {
            if (compara_columnas(matriz, a, b) > 0)
            {
                intercambia_columnas(matriz, a, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pFzPbpoyzUa97wtn).

#### Editado

Sigues sin publicar tu código **completo**; a tu código de transposición le falta contexto por lo tanto es difícil saber en qué falla.

El código que usas para trasponer sólo compara la primera fila (`texto[0]`) pero si quieres ordenar respecto columnas debes tener en cuenta todas las filas que componen la columna, no sólo la primera.

Por otro lado, depende del valor de `largo`, puedes estar leyendo fuera de la matriz en la operación `textoB[0][j+1]` (ya que el límite de `j` es `largo`); además esta comparación es *incorrecta* pues no siempre vas a necesitar comparar la columna posterior a la columna `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo acá abajo una solución que explico en el mismo código. Y no puedo dejar de comentarte que en C++ los arrays y los punteros son el último recurso, nunca el primero. Bueno, igual, acá va...

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <map>

const int f = 6;
const int c = 5;

void obtener_orden(const char* m, int* n)
{
    // en los c caracteres de m está la primera fila
    // F, H, V, D, U
    // la idea es que si su orden actual es
    // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    // pase a ser 
    // 3, 0, 1, 4, 2 
    // o sea: 
    // D, F, H, U, V
    // y guardarse ese nuevo orden en n:

    // como soy muy vago, me voy a ayudar con un std::multimap 
    // http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap
    std::multimap<char, int> posiciones;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        posiciones.insert(std::make_pair(m[i], i));
    }

    // lleno el array n con el nuevo orden:
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "nuevo orden = ";
    for (std::multimap<char, int>::iterator it = posiciones.begin(); it != posiciones.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << "; ";
        n[i++] = (*it).second;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void ordenar_matriz(char* m, int* orden)
{
    // acá la idea es aplicar el nuevo orden que figura en el array orden
    // a la matriz nueva, que también va a tener f filas de c columnas,

    char nueva[f][c];

    for (int i = 0; i < f; ++i) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {  
            nueva[i][j] = m[i*c + orden[j]];
        }
    }

    // y mostramos la nueva matriz con el nuevo orden:
    for (int i = 0; i < f; ++i) {      // recorre cada fila
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {  // y recorre cada columna
            std::cout << nueva[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {  // main() devuelve int

    char matriz[f][c] = {
        { 'F','H','V','D','U' },
        { 'E','L','Q','U','E' },
        { 'P','E','R','S','E' },
        { 'V','E','R','A','A' },
        { 'L','C','A','N','Z' },
        { 'A','Z','Z','Z','Z' } };

    int orden[c] = {0};

    obtener_orden(&matriz[0][0], orden);

    ordenar_matriz(&matriz[0][0], orden);

}
```